# Delete certain array in a JSONArray with JackSon

Tags: java, jackson, gson

I have something like this:

```
    { 
  "Person": {
    "Info": [{
      "name":"Becky",
      "age": 14
      }
    ]
  },
  "FruitsList": {
    "Fruits": [
      {
        "name": "avocado",
        "organic": true
      },
      {
        "name": "mango",
        "organic": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "VegetablesList": {
    "Vegetables": [
      {
        "name": "brocoli",
        "organic": true
      },
      {
        "name": "lettuce",
        "organic": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to remove the array FruitsList and the VegetablesList or perhaps even Person array.
Something like this.

```
{ 
  "Person": {
    "Info": [
      "name": "Becky",
      "age": 14
    ]
   },
  "Fruits": [
    {
      "name": "avocado",
      "organic": true
    },
    {
      "name": "mango",
      "organic": true
    }
  ],
  "Vegetables": [
    {
      "name": "brocoli",
      "organic": true
    },
    {
      "name": "lettuce",
      "organic": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not quite sure what methods to use with in JACKSON libraries to get the right result. I would much appreciate your help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your input JSON string seems invalid, `Info` is not a JSON array.

Comment: you can read the input into a `Map<String, Object>`, remove the keys and serialize the map back to json

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to remove `FruitsList` and `VegetablesList` nodes from root node first, and add `Fruits` and `Vegetables` back to it as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
JsonNode personNode = rootNode.get("Person");
JsonNode fruitsListNode = rootNode.get("FruitsList");
JsonNode vegetablesList = rootNode.get("VegetablesList");
((ObjectNode) rootNode).remove("FruitsList");
((ObjectNode) rootNode).remove("VegetablesList");
((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("Fruits", fruitsListNode.get("Fruits"));
((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("Vegetables", vegetablesList.get("Vegetables"));

System.out.println(rootNode.toString());
```

---

BTW, as I said in OP's comment, your JSON string is **invalid**. A valid one should be `"Person": {"Info": {...}},...`.